# KeyCollection as IEnumerable produces inconsistent LINQ behavior

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, nullable

The following code prints "false"

```cs
IEnumerable<string> x = new List<string>();
Console.WriteLine(x.Contains(null));
```

But this code throws an `ArgumentNullException`:

```cs
IEnumerable<string> x = new Dictionary<string, string>().Keys;
Console.WriteLine(x.Contains(null));
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20428049/3525158) explaining why `Dictionary.ContainsKey` throws if null is passed in, so I'm guessing this behavior is related.  However, in the case of `ContainsKey` I get nice green squigglies, whereas with `IEnumerable` my app crashes:

[image]

The consuming code isn't going to know the underlying type of `IEnumerable` passed to it, so either we need to:

- Not use `IEnumerable.Contains()` with nullable types in general or
- Convert `KeyCollection` to a list before treating them as `IEnumerable`

Is this right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you want to expose the [`Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys) property as an `IEnumerable<TKey>` sequence that allows searching for `null`. An easy way to do it is to wrap the collection in an `IEnumerable<TKey>` implementation, that hides the identity of the collection:

```
static IEnumerable<T> HideIdentity<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    foreach (var item in source) yield return item;
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<string> x = new Dictionary<string, string>().Keys.HideIdentity();
```

This way the LINQ [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) operator will not detect that the collection implements the `ICollection<T>` interface, and will follow the slow path of enumerating the collection and comparing each key using the default comparer of the `TKey` type. There are two downsides to this:

1. The CPU complexity of the operation will be O(n) instead of O(1).
2. The comparison semantics of the [`Dictionary<K,V>.Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.comparer) will be ignored. So if the dictionary is configured to be case-insensitive, the `Contains` will perform a case-sensitive search. This might not be what you want.

A more sophisticated approach is to wrap the collection in an `ICollection<TKey>` implementation, that includes special handling for the `null` in the `Contains` method:

```
class NullTolerantKeyCollection<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<TKey>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection _source;

    public NullTolerantKeyCollection(Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection source)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
        _source = source;
    }

    public int Count => _source.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => true;
    public bool Contains(TKey item) => item == null ? false : _source.Contains(item);
    public void CopyTo(TKey[] array, int index) => _source.CopyTo(array, index);
    public void Add(TKey item) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public bool Remove(TKey item) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public void Clear() => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        => _source.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<TKey> IEnumerable<TKey>.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

static NullTolerantKeyCollection<TKey, TValue> NullTolerant<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection source)
{
    return new NullTolerantKeyCollection<TKey, TValue>(source);
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<string> x = new Dictionary<string, string>().Keys.NullTolerant();
```

This way the resulting sequence will preserve the performance and behavior characteristics of the underlying collection.

**Note:** Checking for `null` with `item == null` instead of `item is null` is intentional. It is consistent with how the `Dictionary<K,V>` class does the check [internally](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3bc1508bb72cf9c24c5f66b1226fd5f1d71ab7dd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L394).

You mentioned a third option in the question: converting the collection to a `List<T>` with the `ToList` LINQ operator. This will create a copy of the keys, and will return a snapshot of the keys at the time the `ToList` was called. It might be a decent option in case the dictionary is frozen, and the number of keys is small.

Comment: +1 for considering performance implications, something I wasn't really thinking about. 
I'll accept this answer since it provides some good workarounds.  I was hoping for a fix that took the form of a compiler error or warning like what @etienne was referring to, but seems like there isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this behaviour is that `Enumerable.Contains<IEnumerable<TSource>>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value)` has a shortcut when `source` implements `ICollection<TSource>`. In these cases it just invokes the `Contains` method of `source`. See the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Contains.cs#L10) for `Enumerable.Contains`.

The `Keys` property of the dictionary is implemented by a `KeyCollection` ([reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs#L1462)). Internally, its `Contains` method includes validation for a non-null key, which you are running into.

If you want to use the non-shortcut linq method for `Contains` you should be able to always call it by supplying a `comparer` parameter in the [other overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-contains-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) of this method - even if the comparer is `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and links, this helped me understand the underlying issue.  Interesting point about using the overload, although it would look strange to do this in practice, and still requires the developer to know about this specific nuance.  So I'd opt for modifying the collection over modifying which overload of `Contains` I call

Answer (score 1):

You could do either of those, but I recommend a third method: enable [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) for your project. That way, you can't pass null to `IEnumerable<string>.Contains`, because `string` does not allow nulls. It's self documenting, how about that.

And if you treat warnings as error, you'll get more than green squigglies, you'll get actual compiler errors, which means no possiblity of crashes.

Comment: I posted a screenshot in the question which was from an interactive notebook with `#nullable enable`, which I believe means I already have that turned on.  `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` seems perfectly happy to accept null.  I'm using dotnet 6.0.401, not sure if that makes a difference